# ZF2 headScript including same file twice

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework2

I am using ZF2 and facing a weird behavior. When I use the headScript to append or prepend some Javascript file, the file is included twice. The same happens with inlineScript.

This is my actual view with the headScript()->appendFile():

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath('js/dashboard.min.js')); ?>
```

With this implementation, when my page is loaded, all the requests are made twice and this is very bad cause are async requests to an API:

```
Test
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Test
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I tried also without the `$this->basePath()`:

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('js/dashboard.min.js'); ?>
```

And got the same behavior.

But if I put this Javascript without the headScript, it just works fine, include once.

```
<script src="js/dashboard.min.js"></script>

// And the output
Test
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

What I can see is that the first include is made when page is loaded and the second some seconds after (2 or 3 seconds).

Someone already faced this behavior? If yes, Did Solve it? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are echoing out the headScript.  Try removing your echo statement, and I believe it will work fine.

Use this:

```
<?php $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath('js/dashboard.min.js')); ?>
```

Instead of this:

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath('js/dashboard.min.js')); ?>
```

Comment: Man, I don't believe. I always use echo... I get the skeleton example and think it was ok (https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As in the skeleton app, you only want to echo it once. If you echo the appendFile call, and echo the headscript later on, that's why you get duplication.

Comment: Nice @TimFountain, I didn't knew this. Thanks for advice.